Three.js click and move logic with background image
Im currently working on a three.js project as stated, we move by clicking on the ground where we want our character to go and so on. Im using the navmesh library and building my ground floor in blender and then im putting on the navmesh before exporting it in my project.
I want to be able to make a "fake" 3D feeling by having the background image as I see in my blender scene in my three.js project but I cant achieve or know how to do it. I attached an image underneath to help undestand.
My scene that I want to have in my project
I want to be able to have the ground that I made with the background image. I want to represent the exact same view to achieve a certain click and go game with that scenery. Most importantly, I do not want to have a static stretched background
Thank you,

Have you considered exporting your Belnder scene as gltf (for example) and loading it into three.js? The background won't be "static," but 1. your character will always be in the correct depth space (including obscuring and clipping), 2. transparent objects in the foreground of the scene will work correctly automatically, and 3. if you upgrade the Blender scene with animations etc., you can directly load them and animate them as part of rendering.
